# Find the value of $a$ for which v is in the set H = span

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the value of $a$ for which $ v = \begin{bmatrix}10\\-6\\6\\a\end{bmatrix}$ is in the set $H = span \{ \begin{bmatrix}-5\\2\\-5\\-3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\-2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-3\\-1\end{bmatrix}\}$

$a = ?$

I found:

$10 = -5x \implies x = -2$

$-6 = 2x - 2y \implies -4 - 2(1) \implies y = 1$

$6 = -5x - y -3z \implies -5(-2) - 1 - 3z \implies z = 1$

$a = 3x + y - z \implies a = -6+1-1 = -6$ but I keep getting the answer wrong, how is $a \ne -6$?

Comment: Wait a minute....is it $6$ or $-6$ ???

Comment: Check out $-3x$....typo in the last line that starts with $a=$

Comment: @imranfat Sorry typo

Comment: @David Typo, fixed now

Comment: @user352790. Now you need to redo the arithmetic...

Comment: @imranfat Thank you, that was the problem :(

Comment: Ok...cool you found it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the augmented system
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-5 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
2 & -2 & 0 & -6 \\
-5 & -1 & -3 & 6 \\
-3 & 1 & -1 & a
\end{array}
\right]
$$
can be row-reduced with the following steps:

- scale row 1 by $-1/5$
- add $-2$ times row 1 to row 2
- add $5$ times row 1 to row 3
- add $3$ times row 1 to row 4
- scale row 2 by $-1/2$
- add $1$ times row 2 to row 3
- add $-1$ times row 2 to row 4
- scale row 3 by $-1/3$
- add $1$ times row 3 to row 4

Performing these operations gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
-5 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
2 & -2 & 0 & -6 \\
-5 & -1 & -3 & 6 \\
-3 & 1 & -1 & a
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a - 6
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that $v\in H$ if and only if $a=6$.